# Padding Property not applying?

Tags: html, css

I wanted it to have a table which was half red and half blue, with some padding between the borders and the text. I just can't figure out why the padding property isnt apply in this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Practice Exercise </title
<style>
.red{background-color:red}
.blue{background-color:blue}
table{border-collapse:collapse;padding:40px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border ="1">
<tr>
<th class="red"> State </th>
<th class="blue"> Capital </th>
</tr>
<td class="red"> Utah </td>
<td class="blue"> Salt Lake City </td>
</tr>
<td class="red"> Texas </td>
<td class="blue"> Austin </td>
</tr>
<td class="red"> Tennesse </td>
<td class="blue> Nashville </td
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a lot of typos in you markup:
i will point them all up.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="red">State</th>
        <th class="blue">Capital</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- missing -->
        <td class="red">Utah</td>
        <td class="blue">Salt Lake City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- missing -->
        <td class="red">Texas</td>
        <td class="blue">Austin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  <!-- missing -->
    <td class="red">Tennesse</td>
    <td class="blue">Nashville</td>  <!-- missing one " after blue, and one > after </td -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

also: you applied the padding on the `table`, you should have applied it on the `td, th` like this:

**CSS**

```
td, th
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/DWyUa/1/)

Comment: Can you explain what you did there?

Comment: Ah thanks, sorry the typos were there only because I retyped it as I was unsure how to copy-paste my code with it being seperated into the box.

Comment: If it answers your question, you should accept it as correct.